# Trying to copy a file in Python script, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

I'm trying to copy a file (image.jpg) from the folder 'src' to the folder 'dst', but I've got an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "exec.py", line 7, in 
>           shutil.copyfile(file, destination)
>         File "C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\s
>       hutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
>           with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
>       **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.jpg'**

This is my code:

```
import shutil, os

source = os.listdir('C:/Users/mike/Pictures/src/')
destination = 'C:/Users/mike/Pictures/dst/'

for file in source:
    shutil.copy(file, destination)
```

Python 3.5 / Windows 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the names, but they don't have the directory prefix on them, you need to add this when copying.

```
for file in source:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('C:/Users/mike/Pictures/src/', file), destination)
```